# Looking for cross-platform mobile database options

Tags: java, android, silverlight, windows-phone-7, cross-platform

I intend to write an app for Windows Phone 7, then port it to Android. Database usage is for persisting a small amount of user-generated data.

I am considering cross-platform databases because I'd prefer the code-bases to be similar, ideally the presentation-layer code would have the biggest differences.

The only cross-platform mobile database I've found so far is [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/), but deployment to the WP7 emulator is a non-starter, plus their documentation emphasized that their Silverlight/WP7 support is still a "work in progress". I'd rather get on with making my app than waiting for their house to get in order.

I may resort to using an XML file, but before I do has anyone else spotted .Net/Java mobile databases out in the wild that are worth a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest SQLite or your own xml implementation. I'm sure there's a library for almost every os out there for managing xml databases. Plus you won't resort on privative or complex open source databases. Remember KISS.

Comment: The possibility of an XML-database library sounds encouraging, but I haven't found anything suitable so far. Still looking though.

Comment: Don't search as xml database, just for an xml library to parse and read from xml files. If you want sql like queries, that's another story. But if there's less than a thousand or so entries, a simple search with dynamic memory techniques would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with SQLite?

Android supports it out of the box, and even though I'm not familiar with WP7 I think it is well supported.

Unless you are looking for a cross-platform **ORM**.

Comment: I agree with your overall recommendation, but SQLite is **NOT** well supported on WP7

Comment: After looking at some SQLite example code, I remembered the part I hate the most is dealing with CRUD! So, yeah, cross-platform ORM is the best, yet I haven't found anything that is as good as .Net's EF code-first, although db4o (for my purposes) would have been an excellent replacement (had it been "ready for prime-time")!

Answer (score 2):

We have an app that is on Android, iOS, and WP7 that all use the same **SQLite** database.  Using a SQLite database is really easy and straight forward in Android and iOS. It is **NOT supported out of the box on WP7** but there are a number of guides to getting it working out there.  I wrote my own guide using the [Community C# SQLite Project](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/) which you can find here: http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app/ but there are several other options that you should be able to find relatively easily.

However, not really knowing what exactly you are trying to save, a database could be overkill.  If it is relatively simple data and/or pretty small, **XML** or **JSON** are both fine options that can be stored, retrieved and parsed easily on all three platforms.

Comment: SQLite seems to be my best option, do you use ORM, or are you writing the SQL yourself?